# tensorflow cannot import name container_types

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, build

I've just compiled tensorflow from source code with GPU support on OSX.
This was with a few hick-ups and hacks along the way:

- based on [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14898) I've checkout commit 49dcb6c769d60206eb845eb249fa3ef6bc333457 from the 24th of August  2017 (to get past the XLA namespace related error)
- I've also manually taken out the `-lgomp` flag as well

Finally I've compiled the .whl file and installed in a virtual environment, however, when I try to import tensorflow, I get these errors:

```
import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Volumes/GP_2T/tensorflow_tutorials/tf_src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Volumes/GP_2T/tensorflow_tutorials/tf_src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.framework_lib import *
  File "/Volumes/GP_2T/tensorflow_tutorials/tf_src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/framework_lib.py", line 102, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.importer import import_graph_def
  File "/Volumes/GP_2T/tensorflow_tutorials/tf_src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import function
  File "/Volumes/GP_2T/tensorflow_tutorials/tf_src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops import resource_variable_ops
  File "/Volumes/GP_2T/tensorflow_tutorials/tf_src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import custom_gradient
  File "/Volumes/GP_2T/tensorflow_tutorials/tf_src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/custom_gradient.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import tape
  File "/Volumes/GP_2T/tensorflow_tutorials/tf_src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/tape.py", line 23, in <module>
    from autograd import container_types
ImportError: cannot import name container_types
```

My setup is OSX 10.11.5 with bazel 0.5.4, CUDA 8.0, cudnn 5.1 and XCode 7.0

Has anyone else bumped into this issue ? 
Any clues on how I could get myself unstuck / what should I double check ?

Comment: install older version of `autograd ¯\_(ツ)_/¯` also I've found that they [moved](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd/commit/7e382b441f81f645568cacfba8591cc70a9c9bd3) `container_types` so this might be the case

Comment: @Aiven Thanks for the tip. I'll follow the container_types thread to see if I can hack my way through it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually solved the issue by pulling the latest version from the repo (currently 1.6.0-rc0) and using a few super helpful github comments on Eigen and Protobuf errors.

More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48833314/how-to-fix-tensorflow-protobuf-compilation-errors-on-osx)