# Error when building TensorFlow 1.7 from Sources on Mac

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to build TensorFlow 1.7 on Mac from sources and it's throwing me this error:

```
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_MattLem/bfcff3d12fe85b0d0756749577ef2f1f/external/protobuf_archive/BUILD:259:1: Linking of rule ‘@protobuf_archive//:js_embed’ failed (Exit 1)
ld: unknown option: -no-as-needed
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 69.677s, Critical Path: 4.50s
INFO: 5 processes: 5 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

**How can I fix this error?**

Comment: If you want the CPU only version try installing using `pip install tensorflow` (I recommend using a [virtual environment](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#installing_with_virtualenv), just in case there are other python modules already on your system that may interfere). For the GPU version, I remember running into some protobuf and eigen library issues a while back with 1.6. Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48833314/how-to-fix-tensorflow-protobuf-compilation-errors-on-osx/48875175#48875175) maybe it helps with 1.7 too ? (sorry,haven't tested TF GPU 1.7 yet).

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thank you! Yeah the weirdest thing is that I did successfully build tensorflow on my friend's laptop (which is also a mac) with 1.8 version like 2 weeks ago. Followed exactly the same steps on other laptop and it was throwing me errors. Then i thought something might be wrong because of the version so thats why I tried 1.7. I will follow you guidelines and see what happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT's a Bazel bug: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5468. Downgrading might work.

Comment: Ahh gotcha! Thank you! will try downgrading then and see what happens!